# Is it unusual for a professor to submit recommendations to other universities more promptly than their own?

Tags: graduate-admissions, recommendation-letter

I am applying to graduate programs at several universities, including the one that I am currently at.  My professors sent their letters of recommendations to the other universities promptly and quickly, but have not sent them to their own university yet, despite sending them at least over 5 automated requests.

I am highly worried because the deadline is coming up in two days.  Is this a common occurrence, and what I should do about it?

Comment: have you bothered to ask them if they have recieved the email, or if they were planning on submitting it on the last day? submitting the the automated request over and over seems passive aggressive, why not communicate ?

Comment: I have checked with the email service people and they have confirmed that emails were sent out and replies have not been received. I will ask them if they are planning to submit it the last day but you can understand this is a bit difficult to express

Comment: I don't understand why this is difficult to express. "Hello letter writers, I just want to make sure that you knew the deadline for X is Y, I really appreciate your recommendation. Thank you for your time."  You are going to have a lot harder (and this isn't hard at all) confrontations in graduate school, time to put on your big boy pants.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because we cannot know why individual people behave the way they do

Comment: Voting to reopen.  I think this is a fine question, describing an unfortunately common circumstance.

Comment: The deadline is today and people are deciding whether to close my question or not!?

Comment: I think the only useful answer for you will be coming from the professors from your home school.

Comment: I have generalized this question and changed it from "read my professors' minds?" to "is this common and what should I do?", which matches the good answers that have been given.  I think it should be fit for reopening now.

Comment: This question has received four other reopen votes... they've just aged away. So while I'm technically reopening this with a single vote, in spirit it's a fifth vote.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's not enough information to say for sure, but one possibility is that they know the deadline isn't strict because they've seen what happens from the inside.  When submitting a letter to another university, it's hard to know how harmful a delay might be, but your recommenders may know that in your department nobody even plans to look at the letters until the end of next week.  (It's not uncommon to schedule a buffer period between the deadline and the beginning of organized review, precisely to give late letters a chance to arrive.)  Or they may trust that their colleagues on the admissions committee will forgive them for being late.

Comment: Or they may just walk down the corridor and deliver their letters verbally.